# Add date to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add current date to MySQL table using PHP. I have the following code:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO book_order VALUES($date)")  or die (mysql_error());
```

MySQL returns this error:

> Incorrect date value: '1996' for column 'date_order' at row 1

`date_order` attribute is type `date`.

I've tried to `echo` the `$date` value and prints out `2013-05-12`

Why I can't add the date to the table and what is this strange *1996*?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588748/converting-php-date-to-fit-mysql-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can send local date use:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO book_order VALUES(NOW())");
```

The your problem is because your SQL have an typo - `$date` variable must be quoted:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO book_order VALUES('$date')")  or die (mysql_error());
```

In addition, if this not work edit your question and paste the result from SQL `EXPLAIN book_order`

Comment: or in the format:(yyyy-mm-dd) - mysql_query("INSERT INTO book_order VALUES(format(NOW(),'YYYY-MM-DD')");

Answer (score 2):

Use [**STR_TO_DATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) :

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO book_order VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('".$date ."','%Y-%m-%d'))");
```

Comment: Read my comment on Owen's answer. You have to wrap the date string in quotes (not only PHP's string quotes, but quotes in the query too). Else, your input will be interpreted as math expression like MattyF stated in his comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

tried

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO book_order VALUES('$date')")  or die (mysql_error());
```

????

Comment: Either escape the quotes in the query like `\"` (which is MySQL-spcific syntax) or use `'` (which is standard SQL syntax). Can't understand the downvote, comment instead. Suggested an edit to correct the errors.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO book_order VALUES('$date')")  or die (mysql_error());
```